# Infinite Dimensional Separable Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis

I've been solving some exercises about Hilbert spaces and come across this problem:

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional, separable Hilbert space. Show that there is a sequence of vectors $(x_n)$ such that $\|x_n\|=1$ for all $n$, and such that $(x_n,x)\rightarrow 0$ for all $x\in H.$

Can anyone help me answer this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let $x_n = e_n$ be an orthonormal basis and use the $\ell^2$ condition.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$. If $x \in H$, then

$$||x||^2= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|(x_n,x)|^2.$$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|(x_n,x)|^2$ is convergent, hence $(x_n,x)\rightarrow 0.$

Comment: Do I need to show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|(x_n,x)|^2$ is convergent? And how about the $\|x_n\|=1.$

Comment: Since $\{x_1,x_2,...\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$ we have $||x_n||=1$ for all $n$. Furthermore we have $x= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x,x_n)x$ for $x \in H$. Now show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|(x_n,x)|^2$ is convergent and $||x||^2= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|(x_n,x)|^2.$

Comment: I tried proving the equality and used Bessel's to prove convergence. But my result is $(x,x_n)$. Is it just the same with $(x_n,x)$ tho $x_n$ is a sequence?